# Getting AUTO_INCREMENT values from an INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

Okay here's the problem:

I have a server and a client that works with this general paradigm:
 - Client makes a "query" request, and gets a query ID (qid)
 - Client makes "result" requests using the qid as many times as it wants.

When a query is placed, it also gets recorded in a database. This is where I'd like the QID to come from: an AUTO_INCREMENT field. The issue is this: when I insert it, I need to immediately get the value from that field back. If I don't know the value, I can't query for it, since the QID is the only primary key.

I tried doing it manually (keeping track of the keys on my own), but there were threading issues. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using PHP? If yes, then can use `mysql_insert_id`. Here is the link to PHP documentation http://us2.php.net/mysql_insert_id

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this right after the insert?

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

I guess if this happens asynchronously, it's possible 2 inserts happen close enough to each other that the following SELECT gets the wrong ID.